# How to respond to a comment that should be posted as an answer

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, moderation

There is an ongoing debate on partial answers posted in comments [here](https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/question-vs-comment-for-questions-seeking-advice-or-opinions), and it would be helpful to the community to have example responses when a user posts an answer that should be a comment or a comment that should be an answer.

While we continue this debate on the gray area in between clear cases, it is also healthy to identify some agreed upon responses to these situations. Above all, it is critical that we build a welcoming and inclusive community. At the least, we want to adhere to the Stack Exchange Code Of Conduct "Be Nice! Policy" (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct)), but I think we can be 'nicer'?

Helpful information to consider:
Meta Post on '[How do Comments Work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)'?
Biology Meta Post on '[Is there a general list of Help Comments](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3547/is-there-a-list-of-generic-help-comments)'?
Biology Meta Post on '[What are some good, informative comments I can leave for new users](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3275/what-are-some-good-informative-comments-i-can-leave-for-new-users)?'
Meta post on '[A guide to moderating comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments)'

**What are some suggested responses to situations where users post comments that should be rephrased as answers, or where they post answers that are more appropriate as comments?** (*keep within 600 character limit of comments!*)

Answer (score 5):

For a comment that should be an answer:

@OP, Your comment would make a useful answer for future users! **Please reword as an answer** (including citations/links). Comments may be deleted, and even partial answers are helpful! For more info see the FAQ: [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Answer (score 3):

I have used something along the lines of:

@OP would you mind adding your comment as an answer rather than just a comment? Comments can get buried and as an answer it will be easier for others to find.

I like explaining a bit why (but still keeping it short) but very much like the link and bolding in Shannon's answer!

Comment: For what it's worth, I do not think we can bold, link, or other text modifications in a comment. Will add in a slight modification in my response above to add more explanation.

Comment: Comments can get not only buried but also deleted. Comments are not meant to be permanent on Stack Exchange. Important information from a comment should go into an answer (new or existing) or question (when the comment improves the question).